# How to combine two Apache htaccess redirect conditions (http to https and non-www to www)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two redirect conditions which work independently fine but I want to avoid the case where both conditions are satisfied (which results in two redirect steps instead of one)

I must confess I am not good with Apache regex so I got them off the net. Any idea how to combine the two (A or B kinda logic with regex)?

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# redirect from http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# redirect from non-www to www https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Output of the multiple redirect result when both conditions are satisfied is shown below:

[image: Output of the multiple redirect result when both conditions are satisfied is shown]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine both rules into one using `OR` condition clause:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Just replace `www.domain.com` with your actual domain name. Also it is better to test this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Answer (score 2):

Just place your non-www to www rule first, as it specifies an https endpoint in the redirect. This rule will trigger regardless to whether the original request was http or https if the non-www condition is met.

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect from non-www to www with https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]   

# redirect from http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Brant, I tried your solution but results same. Will check the order of requests from Apache logs and confirm if any effect. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: it works, just my browser cache still got its data all twisted. I checked the order of requests in access logs and just as you suggested. But I'm gonna stick with **anubhava's** solution as it combines both beautifully. much Thanks.

Comment: @luhfluh Yes, that solution certainly works, it is just more problematic and would need some adjustment if you needed to support a variety of different domain names as seemed to be implied by use of `{%HTTP_HOST}` in the redirect string in the original question.